# Delaying openURL when app launched via remote push through didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue

Here's my app scenario: When user swipes a notification I will launch some other app via URL.
So it basically *launches some other app when notification arrives*.

Currently to handle swiping notification scenario, when

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)
```

method is invoked, within this method, I call `processNotification:` method, which contains:

```
...
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
...
```

- **If push received while app is active**, `url` is opened perfectly fine.
- **If push received by swiping or clicking on notification**, `url` is opened in the background but the currently viewed app is my application. For example if my `url` is `tel:123-456-7890`, iOS starts the call (you can hear the sound) but active app is not `Phone.app`, it is my app.

That seemed pretty strange to me. However if I wait for UI to load, and call `processNotification:` after that, it brings up `Phone.app` window correctly. (bug in platform? because call happens but my UI is on the top.)

I need a method to delay execution of this `processNotification:` call, (maybe through an operation queue) until a view controller is loaded. Otherwise, my app stays on top and the URL is opened in the background.

Comment: Have you looked at `NSTimer` or `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` ?

Comment: @BergQuester, I am just not sure about how much delay should I put to app become active so when I `openURL`, it launches the other app.

Comment: e.g right now I tried delay 0.5, but I'm not sure things will be ready at t=0.5s.

Comment: Timers and delays are added to the run loop and aren't exact. It will not be executed until the current run through the runloop is completed.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know for sure, but I would bet that simply pushing it out to the end of the runloop by doing `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` with a delay of 0 would be enough.

Comment: @ipmcc I think the problem here is that SpringBoard is unable to cope with one app transition being called while another is in progress. An iOS bug of course. `applicationDidBecomeActive:` is called after the transition animation has finished, so it should be safe to open another app there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, I moved the `openURL` into `main_queue` and it seems to be working fine. I did not have to even make that change in `didBecomeActive`

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
});
```

Comment: This is the same as `performSelector:afterDelay:` with delay 0.

Comment: In general, all UI* functions should be done on the main queue.

Answer (score 3):

You should delay your handling of the push notification (i.e. calling `openURL:`) until `applicationDidBecomeActive:`. Keep the parameters you need from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` but only call your handling code in `applicationDidBecomeActive:`.

I think the problem here is that SpringBoard is unable to cope with one app transition being called while another is in progress. An iOS bug of course. You should open a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Delaying the `openURL:` logic to `aplicationDidBecomeActive:` did not solve it unfortunately. The issue is still there. This happens even if the app was the one active before phone goes into lock. If I swipe the push, app is already there when device is unlocked and when it gets the notification and performs `openURL:` and it keeps staying on top. `:-/`

Comment: Another option is to go into "voodoo magic" solutions, such as `performSelector:afterDelay:`. These work wonders, but are risky, as they involve timing issues which can cause additional trouble.

Comment: Yeah, in the question comments, I tried `performSelector:afterDelay:` with some hardcoded value e.g. 0.5 sec, but it was randomly failing with the same issue since hard-coded timing does not guarantee things to be ready. I guess I will be buying some Apple Developer Technical Support tickets.

Comment: Did you `performSelector:afterDelay:` in `didFinishLaunch` or in `didBecomeActive`? I would still recommend doing it in `didBecomeActive`.

Comment: I moved it to `didBecomeActive` now, it performed slightly better with delay of 0.5 s. However, I still see the glitch from time to time. It takes iOS to start phone app 2-3 seconds after my app is ready sometimes. If I couldn't find another solution I'll mark this as correct.

Comment: Could you perhaps make a design change? iOS has limitations and designing applications should be, to some degree, around those limitation. For example, displaying an alert for the user in the form of "Will call number 90347239847, are you sure? [Cancel] [Call]" would alleviate your problem while giving a relatively good experience to the user.

Comment: I solved the problem. Even though app comes to didBecomeActive, applicationState was inactive. I put retries to wait until it becomes active, and when it does, I execute openURL, works quite fine. Thanks for help.

Comment: I think better would be to add an observer on the application state property, instead of polling.

Comment: Adding an observer didn't work for me btw so I had to use a timer to pull

`//[application addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"applicationState" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];`
        
`[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(checkIfApplicationIsActive:) userInfo:userInfo repeats:YES];`